# Finding all possible integer solutions to $x_1+x_2+ \ldots$ where the variables have coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, integers

I know how to find integer solutions to equations of the form $x_1+x_2+x_3=n$. You would use stars and bars and do ${n+2}\choose{2}$.

But what if the equation is of the form $x_1+3x_2+4x_3=n$. This is for the problem where you want to distribute n candies among 3 different sized boxes. One size holds one candy, another holds $3$ candies, and the other holds $4$ candies. And each box must be completely filled.

Is it even possible to use the equation approach to this problem? And if so, how?

Comment: [Generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) are often useful to solve these types of problems (see e.g. [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381404/generating-function-for-the-number-of-positive-integer-solutions-to-the-equation)). It reduces the problem to a purely technical one of finding the power-series coefficients of a certain function.

Comment: It would improve the Question if you specified what the goal is: find whether a solution exists, find all possible solutions, or give a count of all possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, your problem is analogous to:

> Finding the coefficient of $t^n$ in the expansion of
>   $$(1+t+t^2+t^3+\dots)(1+t^3+t^6+t^9+\dots)(1+t^4+t^8+t^{12}+\dots)$$

You can relate your question to this in the following way: 
General term of the above expansion = $t^{x_1}\cdot t^{3x_2}\cdot t^{4x_3}=t^{x_1+3x_2+4x_3}$

And we are requiring the coefficient of $t^n$.

So the coefficient will be equal to the number of solutions of $x_1+3x_2+4x_3=n$.